# Profile view > current Quarter/week Span needs padding

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Hi I think there needs to be some padding above Top badge(current week/quarter). Have a look at image below:

[image]

I think `span.top-badge{ margin-top: 15px;}` would be better. Thanks.

Only I am not the person , please check other accounts as well :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/11559/jesper-blad-jensen-aka-deldy

https://stackoverflow.com/users/167264/thiago-h-de-paula-figueiredo

Comment: Use less jquery, problem solved.

Comment: @gunr2171 , that was really not funny . There needs some css adjustments

Comment: It seems that all those elements are [on one line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bewPb.png), so you would have to pad the spacing between the lines if there were any.

Comment: The better solution would be to move `<span class="top-badge">` outside the `<h2>`

Comment: @gunr2171, please check update